# Symfony 1.4 - getPager additional variables for MySql View

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony-1.4

I use Symfony 1.4 and I would like to query a value of a variable that is defined on the MySQL server and now it unfortunately can not be otherwise (it is a dynamically assigned IP, which changes daily through external API). The corresponding VIEW on a MySQL server containing this variable is working but if I wanted to send different address through `SET @IP = '123.456.789.012'` for testing purposes, it will be saved on the MySQL server, but when I'm trying the same in Symfony in the code/component class/template just before the `$pager->GetResults()`:

> $connection = Propel::getConnection();
>
> $query = "SET @IP='123.456.789.012'";
>
> $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
>
> $statement->execute();

the results of the sfPager show the old address still... but I need to change it during Symfony runtime to verify the credentials ... I think that the sfPager session uses its own connection session to connect to the database and my SETs there are simply not reflected ... or am I wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can try by deleting contents of cache folder